# Install imap module in hostgator vps server

Tags: php, configuration, module, hosting, imap

Again this sever leaving me in pain and their support refuses to include these issues waht they promise to provide before you pay ... ahh any way if some have been gone through this and can guide me how i can istall imap module on this sevrver.
I have the access to control panel, ssh and all config files, just dont know how to use it. Please help .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok have done it !!!

i was trying to put .dll files for imap but this is linux server

in ssh prompt I have hit this command

```
yum install php53-imap
```

then updated php.ini ading `extension imap.so`

and restarted my services , And it worked :)